# Consider the statement: for nonzero $x$ and $y$, $x^2 - y^2 < x^2-2xy+y^2$. Note that this is not necessarily true.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Consider the statement: for nonzero $x$ and $y$, $x^2 - y^2 < x^2-2xy+y^2$. Note that this is not necessarily true.
>
> A. Determine the cases in which the statement is true and prove each of your conjecture. (hint: there ARE FOUR cases)

Comment: Have you tried listing the cases ?  Please show your effort. Also take time to learn formatting expressions

Comment: Our cases are the following:
case 1 : x and y > o
case 2 : x and y < 0
case 3 : x>0 and y<0
case 4 : x<0 and y >0

we havent started anything because we dont know what to do. please help us T.T

Comment: You should edit your question to include the information you offered in the comments.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Start by writing each expression in factored form to get $(x-y)(x+y)<(x-y)^2$. This is clearly false if $x=y$. If $x\ne y$, you can divide both sides by $x-y$ to get much simpler inequalities to solve. Be careful, though: you’ll need to consider two cases in order to get the direction of the resulting inequalities right.